# What happens if I use malloc with the wrong size?

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to learn more about memory allocation, and so I wrote some test code below to see what would happen if I tried to allocate memory of a less size than what I needed.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char *message;
    int number;
} Object;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Object *obj = malloc(sizeof(Object) - 8);   
    printf("The size of the struct is: %ld\n", sizeof(Object));
    printf("The size of what was allocated is: %ld\n", sizeof(*obj));

    obj->message = "Hello there! My name is Chris!";
    obj->number = 435543;

    puts(obj->message);
    printf("%d\n", obj->number);

    free(obj);

    return 0;
}
```

First of all, is sizeof(*obj) the correct way to see how much memory was actually allocated in this case? Second, why am I still able to assign values to struct objects even if I didn't allocate enough space?

My OS is Ubuntu 12.10 64bit, compiler is gcc 4.7.2

Here is the valgrind output:

```
==14257== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14257== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14257== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14257== Command: ./ex
==14257== 
The size of the struct is: 16
The size of what was allocated is: 16
==14257== Invalid write of size 4
==14257==    at 0x400640: main (ex.c:15)
==14257==  Address 0x51f1048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==14257==    at 0x4C2B3F8: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14257==    by 0x400604: main (ex.c:10)
==14257== 
Hello there! My name is Chris!
==14257== Invalid read of size 4
==14257==    at 0x40065A: main (ex.c:18)
==14257==  Address 0x51f1048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==14257==    at 0x4C2B3F8: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14257==    by 0x400604: main (ex.c:10)
==14257== 
435543
==14257== 
==14257== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14257==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14257==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 8 bytes allocated
==14257== 
==14257== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14257== 
==14257== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14257== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Comment: Try using valgrind to see all your memory allocations.

Comment: You are entering the realms of undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour includes the program working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case, you are potentially trying to allocate 0 bytes, because `sizeof(Object)` is 8 in most 32-bit compilers. `malloc(0)` will return `NULL` as its an invalid size to be allocated, and trying to write to address `NULL` will certainly crash your application.

But lets suppose you successfully allocate 4 bytes, and try to write 8 bytes within it. In a single thread application it should probably work without issues, because despite you will be writing to unallocated memory space, it will not be exactly writing to some crazy address lost in the virtual memory.

Howover, if you do this:

```
Object* a = (Object*)malloc(4);
Object* b = (Object*)malloc(4);
```

It is potentially true that `a` and `b` were allocated in serie. It means that, in most 32-bit compilers, writing to `a->number` will overwrite `b->message` with the same value and vice versa, because both will be trying to store information to the same space in memory.

Comment: `malloc(0)` may return a non-NULL pointer and dereferencing that pointer results in undefined behavior (see annex J.2 of C99). So, it may or may not crash, it's undefined.

Comment: I don't get it. I'm on a 64bit system. Valgrind says that I allocated 8 bytes because the size of the struct is 16. But the second paragraph helps me understand a lot.

Comment: The structure size will depend on the compiler, not on the system. 64-bit systems can run 32-bit applications that will use 32-bit memory addresses. In 32-bit application `sizeof` any pointer type will be 4 bytes. `int` is usually 4 bytes too, but it can have 2 bytes in some old compilers, up to 8 bytes in 64-bit compilers, meaning your struct can have 6, 8, 12 or 16 bytes in size depending on those factors.

Answer (score 2):

It is good that you are doing this kind of exploration. Most standard c libraries include non standard extensions that allow you to check the size of memory after it is allocated. You should call that after returning from malloc and see how much memory the standard library is actually allocating if you want to learn more about how `malloc` is implemented. You may find that something as simple as `malloc(1)` can return a sizeable memory chunk.

As some other readers pointed out, you may be askking `malloc` to allocate zero bytes in your example code if you were to recompile on a 32 bit system. It will happily comply and return `NULL`.

Comment: Cool, but why am I still able to assign to struct members and print them?

Comment: Your structure is probably around 12 bytes long. The library is probably allocating more bytes than the length of your structure in any scenario from `malloc(1)` to `malloc(sizeof(*obj))`.

Comment: `malloc(0)` may return NULL, or it may return a valid pointer to zero bytes of memory that has to be released but cannot be accessed.  Both are allowed by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the compiler and the os. On many, it eventually crashes. Definitely not recommended. Can potentially lead to buffer overflow as well.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the subquestion about sizeof: sizeof yields a result based on the type that you are using (in C, there is a separate case for variable length arrays). If you write

```
T* obj = malloc (any value);
```

then sizeof (*obj) just looks at the type of *obj, which is T, and yields the size of an object of type T. It doesn't matter whether the allocation failed and obj is actually NULL, or whether you allocated fewer or more bytes than the size of a T, it doesn't even matter if you didn't call malloc at all and obj is an uninitialised variable.