# Why dynamic allocation of array of pointers crashes?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc

The malloc part crashes in the following code, but only in VS and not in CodeBlocks. As I have learned, that means that I am probably triggering some undefined behavior. But I can't figure out why...

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define TableLength 29
typedef int info;
typedef int tipkey;
typedef struct element
{
    tipkey key;
    info info;
} element;

typedef struct node* nodepointer;
typedef struct node
{
    element element;
    nodepointer next;
} tipnod;
typedef nodepointer table[TableLength];

int main()
{
    table table;

    for (int i = 0; i < TableLength; i++)
    {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < TableLength; i++)
    {
        element el = { i, i };
        table[i] = (nodepointer)malloc(sizeof(nodepointer));
        table[i]->element = el;
        table[i]->next = NULL;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
}```
````

Comment: I strongly encourage you to use fewer typedefs. They make it really awkward to read the code.

Comment: You could avoid this error by using either of the canonical patterns `p = malloc(sizeof *p);` or `p = (T *)malloc(sizeof(T));`.  (Most of us prefer the first one since it is guaranteed to be correct; the latter can be wrong if you get T wrong , but will at least cause a compiler diagnostic in that case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allocating enough memory:

```
table[i] = (nodepointer)malloc(sizeof(nodepointer));
```

You're allocating space for a `nodepointer` instead of a `tipnod` (?) a.k.a `struct node`.  As a result, you're writing past the end of allocated memory when you write to the struct, triggering undefined behavior.

You want to use that for the size instead.

```
table[i] = malloc(sizeof(tipnod));
```

Note also that you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc` as that can hide other errors in your code.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer felt like turning on the lightbulb in my brain. It really helped me clarify my misconception. :)

Answer (score 1):

Tested on VSCode:
Extending @dbush response, you allocating less memory than required and trying to access unallocated memory. you can refer this [What happens if I use malloc with the wrong size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738016/what-happens-if-i-use-malloc-with-the-wrong-size)

Tested on your code:

```
printf("size of nodepointer: %lu\n", sizeof(nodepointer));
printf("size of node: %lu\n", sizeof(struct node));
```

Output:

```
size of nodepointer: 8
size of node: 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid allocation size mistakes.

Allocate to the size of the refenced object and drop the unneeded cast.

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
```

It is that simple.

In OP's case

```
//table[i] = (nodepointer)malloc(sizeof(nodepointer));
table[i] = malloc(sizeof (*table[i]));
// or 
table[i] = malloc(sizeof *table[i]);
// or 
table[i] = malloc(sizeof table[i][0]);
```